# Change comment Indentation Xcode

Tags: xcode

The default behaviour for the Xcode comment keyboard shortcut is to place // at the far left of the selected lines regardless of indentation.

I'd like to change this so that the indentation is taken into account and the // is inserted just before the text to comment.

For example:

```
class MyClass {
    func myFunc() {
//        cmd-/ does this
        // I want cmd-/ to do this
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Comment Here](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/comment-here/id1406737173?mt=12) extension. After downloading:

1. Restart Xcode
2. Go to Xcode -> preferences -> key bindings
3. Search for "Comment Selection" and remove the key binding for it
4. Search for "Comment Here" and add the key binding "command /" for
   the toggle comments option.
5. Your comments are now pretty :)